# Cannot replace all strings when using 'Find' feature in Spyder

Tags: spyder

I'm using Spyder (downloaded as part of Python(x,y)), and when I press Ctrl+F, I can only highlight instances of text but cannot replace all. How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

press `ctrl+H`, and voilà! the field for replacing string appears below the search field

Comment: Anyone know what this is on osx?

Comment: it is not an answer, but: to my experience Spyder is/was very slow under MacOSX, so I switched to Jupyter notebooks

Comment: On ``MacOS`` that shortcut is tied to ``hide spyder``. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35662566/how-do-you-use-replace-in-spyder/38073467#38073467

Comment: Command-R works on the Mac. I'm not sure why the "Replace" command is not listed in the Search menu...

Answer (score 18):

It's now ctrl+R for anyone who is still searching out there

Comment: Yep, we changed this since Spyder 3.0