# How do you use replace in Spyder?

Tags: shortcut, spyder

Well, you start with cursor on your text, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and type replacement. But surprisingly i was not able to found any shorcut for actual replace or replace all action, rather than tabbing 5(!) times or moving my hand for a mouse.

Straightforward enter does nothing, tabbing to replace button and entering replaces, but throws me into the editor. VisualStudio-like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> does nothing.

Am i missing something in spyder shortcuts?

Answer (score 81):

The shortcut for replace is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.

Answer (score 9):

I have the same issue with Spyder, I don't know why this has not been implemented in the editor.

The work around I currently have for multiple replace is to :

1. Copy the replacement term to the clipboard
2. Search(Find/Replace) for the term to replace
3. Use <kbd>F3</kbd> to select the next term
4. Use paste <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to replace it
5. Back to step [3] to find the next term

Hope this helps!

EDIT:

According to Spyder dev @carlos below. Since v3.2 This has now been implemented and you may just press  and move to the next term.

Comment: how to do step 2? EDIT: the shortcut has been changed to ctrl + R

Answer (score 8):

(*Spyder developer here*) Since Spyder **3.2** you will be able to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the replace field to replace the current selection and automatically move to the next one.

Answer (score 4):

Are you on `MacOS`? There is an issue on github suggesting that the <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> shortcut is assigned to "hide spyder". An update will bind <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> as a replacement. As this has just been merged, it will take a few days before a `dmg` is available for MacOS. In the meantime you can go to **Preferences** --> **Keyboard shortcuts** --> **editor: replace text** and change the shortcut binding.

Reference:

https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2914

Comment: Obviously, i'm not on MacOS, since i use CTRL-H and it works.
The question was about what do you do **after** you pressed it and typed replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Why just not use *Notepad++*?

In spyder editor, select the entire code (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>), copy it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) and paste it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) into *Notepad++*. Then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, click on the "Replace" tab/menu (or you can use Tab to navigate) on the window that opens, write the string/value you want to find/replace, write the string/value you want to replace with, hit replace (or replace all: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>; it will replace in the entire code). Do it as many times as you want/need - depending on how many unique values/strings you want to replace in the code. At any stage you can do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to undo some actions or move the code from spyder editor to *Notepad++* again (if you need to). Finally, select all, copy and paste it in the spyder editor and you're done.

It would be nice if spyder had this functionality implemented since it'd speed up the process but until then you can use this workaround. That's what i do also.

Video on how to do it (not mine):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I6-7GBY0ZHY

Comment: Don't copy the whole code into Notepad++. just open your .py file with Notepad++ and edit it.